# Magento User Name and Password are visible in browser network

Tags: magento2, password, admin-user

I don't know it's normal or what but recently I found that `we can see the entered admin username and password in the browser network`

[image: inrsaurabh]

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is normal. How else should a form being sent? You enter the password as clear text, it's encrypted if SSL is used, and then decrypted by the server. There's no way the browser does not know your password when you enter it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are saying if SSL were used than password will be encrypted in the network as well ?

Comment: The password will only be encrypted in the network. The browser will know the value, then encrypt it, send it to the server, the server will decrypt it, and then the server will now the value as well.

Comment: I just tried on live website and in network, i cant see the username and password. Thank you for your time

Comment: in magento ver 1.x we are not able to see the username and password , last time i checked in ver 1.9 with ssl . once i check in ver 2 i will accept your answer again . sorry for this